# If $G$ s.t. $|G|=15$ has only one subgroup of order $3$ and only one of order $5$, then $G$ is cyclic. Generalize to $|G|=pq$, for $p,q$ primes.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group where $o(G)=15$. If $G$ has only one subgroup of order $3$ and only one of order $5$, prove that $G$ is cyclic. Generalize to $o(G)=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes.

Comment: For order $pq$ see Herstein's exercise [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355705/showing-that-a-group-of-order-pq-is-cyclic-if-it-has-normal-subgroups-of-order).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $N$ and $M$ are normal subgroups such that $N\cap M=1$, then $nm=mn$ for every $m\in M$ and $n\in N$.

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355705/showing-that-a-group-of-order-pq-is-cyclic-if-it-has-normal-subgroups-of-order).